# Stored procedure in scheduler in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, scheduling

I am using SQL Server 2005.

I have a stored procedure [say Sp_GetAllMaterialInfo], I want to put it in a scheduler that everyday this stored procedure execute on 2 P.M. daily.
Please let me know the steps I have to follow to achieve in SQL Server 2005

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a sql server agent job.

Answer (score 1):

How to schedule a job in SQL server:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Or if you are using Express edition the approach here might help http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=27 (Gives an example of how to run a procedure a as scheduled task)

Or a free utility to achieve the same thing as SQL Agent is here (I've not used it myself) http://www.lazycoding.com/products.aspx